# Why is log M(x) convex (from Three Lines Theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

In the statement of the Three Lines Theorem we want to show for some function $M:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that $\log M$ is a convex function on $[0,1]$.

Recall:

> $f[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is
>   **convex** if for all $x,y \in [a,b]$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$ we have $$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)$$

The proof of the theorem proceeds to show that for any  $0 \leq s < t \leq 1$ we have $$M(x)^{t-s} \leq M(s)^{t-x}M(t)^{x-s}.$$

How does this imply that $\log M$ is convex according to above definition?
If I apply log on both sides I only get this
$$(t-s)\log(M(x)) \leq (t-x)\log M(s) + (x-s)\log M(t).$$

Comment: noticing $(t-x)/(t-s) + (x-s)/(t-s) = 1$ is a good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
 (t-s) f(x) \le (t-x) f(s) + (x-s) f(t)
$$
for $s < x < t$ is an equivalent condition for convexity.

For $x = \lambda s + (1-\lambda)t$ you have
$$
t-x = \lambda (t-s) \, , \quad x-s = (1 - \lambda) (t-s) \, ,
$$
so that
$$(t-s)\log M(x) \leq (t-x)\log M(s) + (x-s)\log M(t)$$
becomes 
$$
 \log M(\lambda s + (1-\lambda)t) \le \lambda \log M(s) + (1-\lambda) \log M(t) \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks, I tried it myself but did something wrong when I wrote it out. Now it's clear.